# VSCode Syntax Error ; expected

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Not really sure if this is actually an issue, as I've noticed in the past VSCode gives warnings about things that only apply to TypeScript. I'm creating an object constructor in vanilla JS, like this:

```
"use strict";

function Imaging(outputAttr) {
    var output = document.getElementById(outputAttr);

    var svgAttributes = {
       namespace: ['http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg'],
       attributes: { // colon here
        style: "border: 1px solid black", //d in border, b in black
        width: "200", height: "300" }, //t in width
       attributeNamespace : ['http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:xlink', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink']
    };

}
```

Under `var svgAttributes`, I am getting a red squiggly with the error `"; expected"`. Everything works as it should, far as I can tell, but I'm not sure why I'm getting this error in the editor. Am I missing something?

I've noted the exact locations in comments.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is beacuse you have to add a `;` at the end of the `function Imaging` like this :

```
"use strict";

function Imaging(outputAttr) {
    var output = document.getElementById(outputAttr);

    var svgAttributes = {
       namespace: ['http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg'],
       attributes: { // colon here
        style: "border: 1px solid black", //d in border, b in black
        width: "200", height: "300" }, //t in width
       attributeNamespace : ['http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:xlink', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink']
    };

}; // <----- just here
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the issue. Which is what I was expecting given that the semi-colon is considered optional here. I don't like to ignore errors, but I might need to chalk this up to editor wackiness given that it doesn't really effect anything (yet). Thanks.